# Jquery Datatable for reading html from DOM

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using Jquery Data Table, I want to read all html of the data table from DOM instead of rendered page. Can clues please?

Comment: Clue #1 - Learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Clue #2 - Add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example to your question

Answer (score 1):

Reference the [datatables API](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().data()). You can call the following then loop through to get each row data.

```
 var data = table.rows().data();
 for(var i; i<=data.length;i++)
 {
    console.log(data[i].columnName);
 }
```